# How to convert object to json format using KnockoutJS?

Tags: knockout.js

I need an object converted into json format. I tried the below code but object is not converted into json format.

```
 function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    var jsonData = {       
            name: "Johnny",
            surname: "Boy"        
    }

    var obj = ko.toJS(jsonData);          
};

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: `ko.toJS` and `ko.toJSON` are two different methods. Are you trying to convert to JSON or not?

Comment: Your jsonData is a JSON Object

Answer (score 0):

See [these docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html#converting-view-model-data-to-plain-json), you need to utilize the `ko.toJSON` method:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  var jsonData = {
    name: "Johnny",
    surname: "Boy"
  };

  var json = ko.toJSON(jsonData, null, 2);

  console.log(json);
  self.myjson = json;
};

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<pre data-bind="text: myjson"></pre>
```

The second and third argument are optional. As I entered them they imply you want formatted output, `ko.toJSON` uses the same arguments as [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) offers.

As a footnote, `ko.toJS` is also useful, mainly to convert an entire view model (but only its public properties) to a plain JS object. See this example:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  // Not visible in ko.toJS / ko.toJSON:
  var privateproperty = "privacy!";
  self.alerter = function() { alert('Hi!'); };
  
  // All visible in ko.toJS / ko.toJSON:
  self.name = ko.observable("Johnny");
  self.surname = ko.observable("Boy");
  self.publicproperty = "publicly!";
};

var vm = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);

console.log(ko.toJS(vm)); // outputs a JS *object*
console.log(ko.toJSON(vm)); // outputs it as a json-string
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
See console.log output...
```